# Which subject does the participle phrase refer to in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

> Small wonder, when he would fuel himself with seven pints of lager and his “magic” Coke, **swigged from a litre bottle topped up with vodka**, to “get his nerves in shape”.

I have a question about this sentence from an [article](https://www.economist.com/node/21552164).
Is the bold part a further explanation of the "lager and his magic coke" or the "magic coke" only?

Comment: It pertains to "Coke", the soft drink.  Seven pints don't fit into a liter bottle.  But let's say that the size of the bottle wasn't given.  Do people mix lager, Coke, and vodka into a single concoction?

Comment: You can't put seven pints of lager and coke in a litre bottle ;) Grammatically it's a bit ambiguous, but there's only one meaning that makes sense here, I think.

Comment: There is also the point that the coke is `"magic"`this is likely because it is `"topped up with vodka"`.

Answer (score 1):

It's *his "magic" Coke*.

You are right that it is ambiguous, but these contextual clues make it lean strongly towards pointing to *his "magic" Coke* without *seven pints of lager* being part of it.

- Coke (at least in the US) is usually sold in 2-liter bottles
- Coke (the soft drink) is often part of a mixed drink, for example, Jack Daniels.  Therefore "topped up with vodka" really wouldn't involve the beer (lager).
- I really have never heard of beer and vodka being mixed though I'm sure someone somewhere has tried it.
- *Swig* is something you do to a bottle, but less so to a "pint of lager" (unless it was clearly in a bottle).
- "Magic" can mean "enhanced" and a soft drink with liquor mixed in it fits that use of "magic."